# Chromium / puppeteer on github actions and azure static web apps libX11-xcb.so.1 failure

Tags: vue.js, puppeteer, github-actions, gridsome, azure-static-web-app

I'm building a vue/gridsome app that uses a critical css extract plugin.
It all runs fine locally but I'm struggling with github action builds.

```
Extract critical CSS (1 pages)
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/github/workspace/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: error while 
loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've searched for solutions and it seems there are linux / unbuntu dependencies missing so I tried to add them to my yml workflow following this:https://medium.com/@cloverinks/how-to-fix-puppetteer-error-ibx11-xcb-so-1-on-ubuntu-152c336368

```
 steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      submodules: true         
  - name: Req
    run: sudo apt install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
  - name: Build And Deploy
    id: builddeploy
    uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
    with:
```

It still fails, am I missing a step or is there a limitation with azure static web apps and github actions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you [try this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix)

```sh
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 lsb-release wget xdg-utils
```

Comment: I had the same problem too back in the days. Some Puppeteer libs does not exist on linux for whatever reasons. (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6349). If possible try to use something else. Does a clean puppeteer install works for you? Does the hello world example (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#usage) runs on your server without the missing dependencies error?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and the following discussion thread has a workaround suggested: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/99

"Our product engineering team is aware of the issue, but unfortunately there is no ETA for a permanent fix. As Static Web Apps moves closer to General Availability (GA), a lot of these issues should be resolved as they are currently maturing the product out of public preview and trying to get it ready for GA."

To benefit the community:
Copied the discussion that you had with my colleague Bryan on the [Microsoft Q&A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/178768/chromium-puppeteer-on-github-actions-and-azure-sta.html) -  Thanks for the follow-up and update, Michael. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ajay, I meant to update this thread - the solution for me was: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/99#issuecomment-680288588

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the update, Michael.